# RecylerView not displaying items when using swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

In the below code I am trying to displaying a list using RecyclerBiew in android to display the listview.

But I am trying to get the building list it is showing this error.I am getting the below error .After displaying the list I am able swipe from right side there I am displaying options to edit and delete.

Below Adapter class I am getting the error

can any one help me where I did the mistake.

The exception is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to helper.GetBuildingList
        at com.deepshiIkha.lightingsystem.SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:40)
        at com.deepshikha.lightingsystem.SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:21)
```

The adapter onBindViewHolder method is

```
 public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList <GetBuildingList> buildingLists;

    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <GetBuildingList> objects) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.buildingLists = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final GetBuildingList item = buildingLists.get(position);

        viewHolder.tvName.setText((item.getName()) + "  -  Row Position " + position);


        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

        // Drag From Left
//        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));

        // Drag From Right
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));


        // Handling different events when swiping
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                //you are swiping.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the BottomView totally show.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                //when user's hand released.
            }
        });

        /*viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if ((((SwipeLayout) v).getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Close)) {
                    //Start your activity

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getEmailId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });*/

        viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getName (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


//        viewHolder.btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on Map " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        viewHolder.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Edit  " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                buildingLists.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, buildingLists.size());
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buildingLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }


    //  ViewHolder Class

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        TextView tvName;

        TextView tvDelete;
        TextView tvEdit;


        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
             tvDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
            tvEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);



        }
    }
}
```

GetBuilding:

```
public class GetBuildingList {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String ID;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String Name;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/

Comment: share entire adapter code and GetBuildingList class code

Comment: @HardikBambhania see my adapter code

Comment: @jyothi34567 : item.getName() is this return string ?

Comment: @HardikBambhania No it is not not printing anything .For item postion I am getting 1

Comment: @jyothi34567 : can you please also share GetBuildingList.java class code

Comment: @HardikBambhania can you please check out I had share GetBuilding class

Comment: @HardikBambhania please check out and let you know

Comment: @jyothi34567 : I am not able find anything wrong in your adapter code.May be you are passing wrong arraylist in adapter constructor.

Comment: @HardikBambhania Please check my code in tell me where i did the wrong